# Which statistical method to use: Kruskal-Wallis, one-way ANOVA, or another?

Tags: r, statistical-significance

I have a [csv file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/heh774rqixycxy8/csv1.txt) with time data values (elapsed times) of different lengths for three groups X, Y and Z, knowing that:

- the samples are independent
- normality checking via Shapiro-Wilk fails for Y and Z groups (it does not fail for X but according to X's Q-Q plot X should not be normally distributed)
- the stardard variations are (sd(x) in R): sd(X)=0.003577565 , sd(Y)=0.013948358 , sd(Z)=0.006929825 (Does these tell the presence of unequal variances?)

I have generated some plots (boxplot, and Q-Q plots for X, Y and Z) that you can download from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3bcyhfmr2lw5q8i/plots.zip).

What statistical method should I use to determine statistical significant differences between the three groups? Must I use Kruskal-Wallis instead of one-way ANOVA?

Thanks

Comment: What sort of difference are you looking for?  Difference in location (mean?  median?)  Also, with this small a sample size, I don't think you can conclude that these standard deviations are different...

Comment: I am looking for the difference between the means. Regarding the sample size, it may limit the external validity of the study, but I am happy if for this small study I can determine somewhere a statistical difference between the means of X, Y and Z, that is, that a difference was not by chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the numerical values of three standard deviation estimates is not the way to decide if the variances are different.  There is an F test that you can use.  Eyeballing a qq plot doesn't necessarily make it clear that a distribution is non normal.  The Shapiro-Wilk test is appropriate for that.  However if the sample size is small it may take a large departure from normality to detect a significant difference. In this case it is safer to apply the Kruskal Wallis test rather than the F tests.

Comment: Should I use the Fligner-Killeen and reject that the variances are the same if p < 0.05? Also, is there a minimum sample size so that the results of variance homogeneity tests and of normality tests can be interpreted with confidence?

Comment: If you do the Kruskal Wallis test homogeneity of variance is not an issue.  There is no specific minimum sample size to test for normality.  The degree of skewness and kurtosis of the distribution determines what sample size is needed.  Large departures from normality can be detected with fewer samples than moderate ones.

Comment: Although it must be pointed out that the Kruskal-Wallis test tests for a difference between medians, not means.  However, I personally don't run into many real-world situations where a priori it seems likely that, even if there's a substantive difference between the true medians of the distn's, the means are actually pretty much the same.

Comment: @jbowman: I don't know if this adds much to this question, but when I tested first with one-way ANOVA (which tests means) the result was statistically significant (p < 0.001). What I just need here is for the statistical test to check that the results for X, Y and Z were not by chance, as they standout for X (I don't dare to generalize to the whole population which happens to be huge).

Comment: @mljrg: I do that sort of thing too, more informally testing that non-Normality hasn't screwed me up than actually testing for the significant difference itself.

Comment: What I often do when i am in doubt is apply both tests. If the p-values are close then assuming normality was not a terrible assumption.  I realize jbowman's point that one is testing mean difference for a normal distributions while the other is looking for a location shift in a nonparametric framework but I still view them as looking at the same thing.

Comment: The problem is: the more I read about how to chose a test the more I get confused!! So my strategy is: in doubt "bomb" the data with both parametric and non-parametric versions and if both are p < 0.05 then I am done; otherwise, I have to work harder to choose the right test. I thought this should be more easy, but unfortunately (some) statistical packages do not help much with these decisions (I am using R).

Comment: @MichaelChernick - I agree, it's pretty rare that you wind up comparing two distributions with medians different enough to detect but means that are pretty much the same (or vice versa.)  However, it is a "gotcha" if it gets written up.